# Why doesn't the backspace key work in insert mode?

Tags: insert-mode

Trying to delete characters in insert mode with the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key sometimes doesn't seem to work. I can <kbd>backspace</kbd> *sometimes*, but at other times it does nothing; the cursor doesn't go to the left, and absolutely nothing seems to happen.

I noticed this using gVim in Windows.
The <kbd>backspace</kbd> seems to work as expected while using Vim from the terminal in most Linux systems however.

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can I make the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key delete characters as usual?
3. Is this behaviour intended as a feature? In other words: are there better alternatives to the <kbd>backspace</kbd> to delete characters in insert mode?

Comment: While the answer below correctly solves your problem, I've found that disabling keys such as arrow keys or backspace help you get used to doing things more properly. Backspace in vim is done with `X` (and delete with `x`), but often what you really wanted to do was `db` for example to delete until the beginning of the word, or `daw` to delete the whole word etc. If you have backspace available, you risk using this suboptimal key in more cases than necessary.

Comment: @Shahbaz I disagree: While in insert mode it makes sense to be able to make minor corrections using the backspace key. I agree that one should learn how to use the normal mode commands, but it is not inproper to use backspace while in insert mode for minor corrections.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg, in the case of backspace I agree (actually I don't have it disabled myself). However, it looks like the OP has the default behavior of backspace which doesn't work for example with start of line, but works within the line. Still, the OP has better options than backspace. For example, instead of backspacing to the previous line, one can use `J` which takes care of the whitespaces as well. In short, backspace is fine for quick typo fixes during writing, but other than that there are better alternatives.

Comment: The problem of many people isn't a disagreement with the feature per se but  that it's not the only editor they use. Since they use multiple editors it's counter-intuitive to switch paradigms related to backspace so they prefer a subset of the vim features.

Comment: If you have installed [vim-faq](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim_faq), you can get an offline answer there: `:h vim-faq` and search `/backspace`. The hard to memorize tag is [`:h faq-12.26`](https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-12.26).

Comment: Yeah this is a feature, in vim default settings Ctrl+h acts like a backspace in insert mode.

Answer (score 293, accepted):

tl;dr: Add this to your [`vimrc`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#vimrc) to make the backspace work like in most other programs:

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

---

## Longer answer

Though the default behaviour may be surprising, the backspace "not working" can be considered a *feature*; it can prevent you from accidentally removing indentation, and from removing too much text by restricting it to the current line and/or the start of the insert.

[`:help 'backspace'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27backspace%27) tells us:

```
Influences the working of `<BS>`, `<Del>`, `CTRL-W` and `CTRL-U` in Insert
mode.  This is a list of items, separated by commas.  Each item allows
a way to backspace over something:

value     effect
indent    allow backspacing over autoindent
eol       allow backspacing over line breaks (join lines)
start     allow backspacing over the start of insert; CTRL-W and CTRL-U
          stop once at the start of insert.
```

So what do these values mean exactly?

**indent**
Vim adds automatic indentation for many filetypes; by default, you're *not* allowed to backspace over this; the rules of what is considered to be 'autoindentation' are somewhat subtle, for example, if we would type this (where █ is the cursor):

```
if (true) {
    █
```

Backspacing won't work.

But if we would then add a command and the `}`, and go back up, we *are* allowed to remove the indentation:

```
if (true) {
    █fun()
}
```

This is because in the first example, Vim determined it should add 1 level of indentation when you pressed Enter; but in the second example, Vim didn't autoindent anything, it's just Tab characters or a few spaces.

Also see [`:help 'autoindent'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27autoindent%27)

**eol**
This should be the most obvious, pressing Backspace also removes EOL markers (`\n` or `\r\n`); if disabled, Backspace will do nothing if you try to delete a EOL marker.

**start**
This means you can *only* delete text that you've inserted since insert mode started, and you can't delete any text that was previously inserted.

### So what's the default setting?

> I noticed this using GVIM in windows. The backspace seems to work as expected while using VIM from the terminal in most Linux systems however.

The reason for this is because many Linux distro's ship with pre-made vimrc files which set some common options. For example on my Arch Linux system I have `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/archlinux.vim` with:

```
set nocompatible
set backspace=indent,eol,start
" ... and a few more...
```

If you install Vim on Windows, the default is to use the default vimrc and gvimrc that Vim ships with.

The *Vim* default is an empty value for `backspace`. The Arch Linux, Debian, CentOS, or `$other_distro` default may be different.

## Normal mode

This question is about Backspace in insert mode, but let me also add some brief remarks about Backspace in normal mode.

In normal mode, the Backspace acts as `h`, it just goes to the left.

By default, the backspace will go to the previous line if at the start of a line (as if `eol` was in `backspace`); you can control this behaviour with the [`'whichwrap'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27ww%27) option  through the `b` flag (enabled by default).

You can also make backspace delete characters by mapping it to the `X` command:

```
nnoremap <BS> X
```

Comment: I think that `"_X` would be "more natural" behaviour for `<BS>`.

Comment: Worth noting that almost no distribution ships with the default behavior. The only one I've noticed was msys2 and that wasn't probably a decision but its nature of being underdeveloped.

Comment: @krehwell, about your edit, vimrc is not *always* `.vimrc`, since on Windows platforms it's actually called `_vimrc`. Recent versions of Vim also accept `~/.vim/vimrc` or `vimfiles\vimrc` on Windows. So I actually prefer Martin's original generic phrasing here.

Comment: I linked to it `:help vimrc` now, although that's perhaps not the gentlest of introductions as it contains quite a few things that don't really matter.

Comment: How to do this for `nvi`? It does not support `set backspace`.

Comment: I don't think nvi supports any of this @t7e; you map be able to use `:map`

Answer (score 6):

Just in case anyone is experience not explainable `<BS>` behavior using ConEmu on Windows, you may have to remap the `<BS>` key to:

```
inoremap <Char-0x07F> <BS>
nnoremap <Char-0x07F> <BS>
```

[More information](https://conemu.github.io/en/VimXterm.html#vim-bs-issue)

Answer (score 4):

```
set backspace=2
```

is used with v5.4 and earlier. worked for me on mac.

looks like on mac i have v3.2:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

All versions past 3.2 use the GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3), which Apple isn't in favor of supporting. A discussion on reddit about this is [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/7v97ls/why_doesnt_apple_use_any_gpl_v3_unix_packages_in/).

You can upgrade to the newest Bash with:

```
brew install bash
```

this allows to take advantage of programmable completion highlighted [here](https://itnext.io/programmable-completion-for-bash-on-macos-f81a0103080b).

Answer (score 0):

If `set backspace=indent,eol,start` is the last line of your `vimrc`, none of solutions will work.

Add one more rule after this, eg:

```
set ruler
```

Comment: That seems pretty weird to me, could you explain why adding another command to your vimrc would make the previous one work?

Comment: I placed it at the last line of my `.vimrc`, and it works perfectly fine! ✌️

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked for me.
The problem was that I was using MobaXTerm, which replaced backspace with C-h by default, and had this line in ~/.vimrc:

```
inoremap <C-h> <Left>
```

as a result, effectively, all my backspaces were replaced with <Left> keypresses.
The solution was to go to MobaXTerm settings -> Terminal -> Local shell settings, and disable "Backspace sends ^H".

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh`, you might additionally need to put

```bash
bindkey -v '^?' backward-delete-char
```

to your `.zshrc` file. Relying on the following [response](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/290403/457210).