Neovim configuration to join lines with BACKSPACE
On insert mode, at the end of the line, how to make Neovim joins the current line with the next one when hitting Del?
And harmoniously, on insert mode, at the start of the line, how to make Neovim join the current line with the previous one when hitting Backspace?
What are the Lua script setting which probably will have some cursor position check inside?

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

The first behavior (joining with the next line) can be achieved by having eol as part of the backspace option.
The second behavior (joining with the previous line) can be achieved by having start as part of the backspace option.
Here is how to ensure that in vimscript:
set backspace+=eol,start

Here is how to ensure that in lua:
vim.opt.backspace:append("eol,start")


It might be worth editing the answer at https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2162/10604 to add the Lua version

@D.BenKnoble I have reported the modification to the answer. I believe indeed that we have make sure we provide Neovim answers (Neovim is by far the most popular tag and Neovim plugins are by the far the most popular plugins).
